# Scrollview scrolls after the contents

Tags: android, android-scrollview

In my application I am showing some items using Expandable Height GridView (EHGV). Above EHGV there is pager layout and both pager layout and EHGV are inside a scrollview. My issue is after changing the screen orientation when I scrolls down the page, the page will get scrolled after the contents (as shown in the attached image).

[image]

First time when the page is launched, scroll works fine but after orientation, scrollview get scrolled more. Please give me a solution for this.

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/img_progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/big_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <com.xyz.xyz.ObservableScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/pager_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/images_pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/dashboard_grid_banner_item" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/image_count"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:background="#00000000"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/pager_layout">

                    <com.xyz.xyz.ExpandableHeightGridView
                        android:id="@+id/grid_two"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="26dp"
                        android:fadingEdge="none"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:horizontalSpacing="26dp"
                        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:numColumns="2"
                        android:overScrollMode="never"
                        android:scrollbars="none"
                        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                        android:verticalSpacing="26dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.thoughtripples.mandmdemo.ObservableScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

<include layout="@layout/gradient_header" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
    app:theme="@style/Toolbar" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: a scrollable view should not be inside another  scrollable view.i.e gridview shouldnot be inside scrollview

Comment: That's why I am using ExpandableHeightGridView instead of GridView

Comment: So, i think your ExpandableHeightGridView implementation is not good

Answer (score 0):

set `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`

Comment: Tried but still the issue remains